# Update listview on javafx by other thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I need to update a listview on javafx, i tried two solution:

1.

```
Task task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override public Void call() {
        while (true){
            visitsDataList = reqController.getVisits(userBean);
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    observableList.clear();
                    observableList.setAll(visitsDataList);
                    listVisits.setItems(observableList);
                    listVisits.setCellFactory(List -> new CustomVisitRow());
        });
        try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
};
```

2.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            visitsDataList = reqController.getVisits(userBean);
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                observableList.clear();
                observableList.setAll(visitsDataList);
                listVisits.setItems(observableList);
                listVisits.setCellFactory(List -> new CustomVisitRow());});
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();}}}}).start();
```

but I am not convinced because I believe that too many Runnable are created. there are other solutions? 
which of my solutions is the best?

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with creating that many Runnables.  They’ll get garbage collected quickly enough.  But for a JavaFX value that changes every ten seconds, you should create a [ScheduledService](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html) and bind the ListView’s [items property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#itemsProperty%28%29) to the ScheduledService’s [last value](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html#lastValueProperty%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

Every loop you sleep the thread for ten seconds, which means you're creating a `Runnable` and submitting it for execution on the *JavaFX Application Thread* once every ten seconds. Ten seconds is an eternity to a computer. In other words, you are not creating too many `Runnable` objects nor are you overwhelming the FX thread. However, there are some improvements that could be made.

1. You don't need to call `ObservableList#clear()`, `ListView#setItems`, or `ListView#setCellFactory` every loop. For one, setting the cell factory only needs to happen once when you first create and configure the `ListView`. And assuming the `observableList` instance has been set on the `ListView` before starting your `Thread` then calling `#setAll` is sufficient. That method is equivalent to calling `#clear` followed by `#addAll`.

   ```java
   new Thread(() -> {
     while (true) {
       List<Visit> visits = reqController.getVisits(userBean);
       Platform.runLater(() -> observableList.setAll(visits));
       try {
         Thread.sleep(10_000L);
       } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
         break;
       }
     }
   }).start();
   ```
2. Consider using a [`javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html) instead.

   ```java
   // ScheduledService class
   public class VisitRefreshService extends ScheduledService<List<Visit>> {

     private final ObjectProperty<User> userBean = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "userBean");
     private final ObjectProperty<Controller> reqController = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "reqController");

     // getters, setters, and property getters omitted for brevity

     @Override
     protected Task<List<Visit>> createTask() {
       return new Task<>() {

         final User user = getUserBean();
         final Controller controller = getReqController();

         @Override
         protected List<Visit> call() throws Exception {
           return controller.getVisits(user);
         }   
       }
     }
   }

   // Using the ScheduledService
   VisitRefreshService service = new VisitRefreshService();
   service.setReqController(...);
   service.setUserBean(...);
   service.setExecutor(...); // Or don't set to use the default Executor
   service.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(10.0));
   service.setOnSucceeded(event -> observableList.setAll(service.getValue()));
   service.setOnFailed(event -> service.getException().printStackTrace());
   service.start();
   ```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, i have choice the first solution. I have another problem, I have to kill the thread but if I call join () from the main thread during sleep () the main thread will wait for the sleep to end. I break the while cycle and tried this solution but I don't know if it's okay: `listThread.interrupt();
           listThread.join();`

Comment: Why do you want to `join()`? Simply have the code respond to the `interrupt()` and exit the `while` loop.

Comment: I want `join()` it because after `interrupt()` thread status is `TIMED_WAITING` and not `TERMINATED`. Many new threads can be created by user actions and consequently many thread `TIMED_WAITING`  existing.

Comment: That's why you should be using a thread pool (e.g. `ExecutorService`) with a maximum number of threads. A `ScheduledService` uses an `Executor`, which is the superinterface of `ExecutorService`. Also, the `Thread#sleep(long)` method should throw an `InterruptedException` almost immediately after the thread is interrupted—catch it and break out of the loop. If possible, you should design `#getVisits` to be interruptible as well. And note, there's also `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: I have an additional problem when I make a request to the MySQL database from the DAO. `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: The driver was unable to create a connection due to an inability to establish the client portion of a socket.
This is usually caused by a limit on the number of sockets imposed by the operating system. This limit is usually configurable. 

For Unix-based platforms, see the manual page for the 'ulimit' command. Kernel or system reconfiguration may also be required.
For Windows-based platforms, see Microsoft Knowledge Base Article 196271 (Q196271).`

Comment: As that's completely unrelated to this question I suggest asking a new question. Don't forget to create and provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem.